# WP_Query in a shortcode

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I am trying to put several queries in a shortcode so that I can call them in a page instead of using custom templates. I got my query going but I only see some of the content on the page. The image shows up, the text shows up but none of the html markup is showing up. Is there a Wordpress function that I need to pass this all through so it doesn't strip the HTML?

```
function band_query($atts) { ?>
    <ul>
    <?php                           
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "category" => '',
        "number" => ''
    ), $atts));

    $band = new WP_Query( array(
        'category_name' => $category,
        'posts_per_page' => $number
    ));
    $output = '';
    // The Loop
    if( $band->have_posts()):
        $output .= '<div id="band_bio">';
        $output .= '<ul>';
        while ( $band->have_posts() ) : $band->the_post(); 
            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= '<figure>' . the_post_thumbnail('band', array('class' => 'left marg_right1')) .' </figure>';
            if ( has_excerpt()){
                $output .= the_excerpt();
            } else {
                $output .= the_content(); 
            }                                   
            $output .= '<div class="relative"><a href=' .the_permalink() . 'class="button1">  <span></span><strong>Read More</strong></a></div>';
            $output .= '</li>';
        endwhile; 
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $output .= '</ul>';

    $output .= '
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="prev"></a>

    <a href="#" class="next"></a>

    $output = apply_filters('the_content', $content);   
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode("band_page", "band_query");
```

Comment: You forgot a closing quote. Look at the output of the syntax highlighter.

Comment: And the first `<ul>` is outside of `$output`. Also, using a nice indentation in the code makes it easier to read and debug.

Comment: my syntax highlighter doesn't show a missing anything. I don't see one either. As far as the indenting. Is there a trick to getting it to work on this site? I do indent my code and then I have to spend 10 minutes trying to make it look readable here. Eventually, I get it close enough and post it. It loses all formatting when I copy it over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are constructing the `$output` variable, you need to consider

```
get_the_post_thumbnail()
get_the_excerpt()
get_the_content()
get_permalink()
```

that *return* the values instead of

```
the_post_thumbnail()
the_excerpt()
the_content()
the_permalink()
```

that *echo* the values.