# wordpress loop giving me content

Tags: plugins

I have this code which is supposed to give me only the titles of the pages. 
Instead is returning all of the post content for the first page after giving me what I want instead of just the page title.

```php
function gridpost($atts) { 
query_posts(array('showposts' => 44, 'post_parent' => 256, 'post_type' => 'page'));

while (have_posts()): the_post();
$content .=get_the_title();               
 endwhile;

return $content;
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data

}//end of functioon 

add_shortcode('peter_pgrid', 'gridpost');
```

Comment: I would avoid using `query_posts` at all costs, and your `wp_reset_query` is after the `return`, it will never reach that point so no cleanup happens

Comment: Thank you for the reply, whats an alternative?

Comment: start with an empty $content before the 'while' code: `$content = '';`

Comment: WP_Query and `get_posts`, I'd recommend the first as it works similarly to what you already have. A standard `WP_Query` loop will avoid these kinds of accidents

Comment: I need some code examples.

Comment: Ended up fallowing https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96599/wp-query-in-a-shortcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 main issues here

#### 1. The `$content` variable

This variable is first seen here:

```php
$content .=get_the_title();
```

But it seems to have been plucked out of thin air! Computers need to be told explicitly what to do, and there's no *you know what I mean*. You have to tell it about things before you use them, or it won't know what you mean.

In this situation, PHP will generate a warning/notice in your error log about this, then substitute it for `""` or an empty value. This is PHP trying to be helpful, but it will fill your PHP error log very quickly, and it can lead to unexpected problems and strangeness.

#### 2. `query_posts`

Purge this function from your memory and burn all traces of it with the fire of a thousand suns. There is no good or valid use of this function in day to day use, and it's a great way to break pagination, slow down pages, and cause problems.

Instead:

- If you want to change the posts WP shows on a page, use the `pre_get_posts` filter.
- If you're happy with the posts WP shows, but want to query an additional set of posts, perhaps for a block or a widget, use `WP_Query` and a standard loop. e.g.:

```php
$q = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
]);

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
        // display this post
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // cleanup after ourselves
} else {
    // nothing was found
}
```

The above query will fetch 5 pages

#### 3. Return Statements and Order

`return` means end the function and pass back this value. The code has a super important call to `wp_reset_query`, but for some reason it's been placed after the `return` statement, making it impossible to reach for PHP.

As a result, the shortcode exits before the cleanup can happen. But now, the main loop that had just a single post in it, now has all the posts `query_posts` dragged in instead, so instead of stopping and continuing to the comments area or the footer, it goes back and loop around.

Remember, order matters. Code is ran from top, to bottom. What the code has done is the equivalent of these shopping instructions:

1. buy eggs
2. buy milk
3. stop reading these instructions and go home
4. buy bread

Suffice to say bread will never be bought.

#### Miscellaneous Notes

- Indent indent! A good code editor will auto-indent for you, don't leave code unindented, there's a whole group of bugs and mistakes that are impossible if you indent code
- Don't hardcode post IDs and category IDs in your code. Since you're using a shortcode, pass them in as attributes!
- You might want to wrap your titles in tags of some sort so they don't appear all smushed up together on a single line
- I see you capped your posts to 44, this is good! A lot of people use `-1` to show all, and this can be very bad for performance

Comment: Thank you!! Although when I build onto this and use other meta data such as this, the thumbnails display above the original shortcode, but the titles go in the correct place. $content .=the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 240)). ' '.get_the_title();

Comment: That's unfortunate but your original question made no mention of thumbnails. Consider opening another question for this new issue, but keep in mind this isn't a discussion/support forum, it's a Q&A site